# Getting error: Msg 8134, Level 16, State 1, Line 1

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, divide-by-zero

I have reviewed the other replies to this problem, but cannot find the appropriate response to my situation.  I am trying to divide "actual hours" by "estimated hours".  However, estimated hours can be null (no entry) or zero.  Actual hours can be zero.  So when I get to the division statement, I can't have estimated hours as null or actual hours as zero.  My "coalesce" statements don't appear to be helping. Any advice would be helpful.

```
SELECT PUV.ProjectName, PUV.[Project ID], PUV.[Project Director], PUV.[Project Owner (Manager)], PUV.[Project Type1], **COALESCE( PUV.[Estimated Hours], 0 ) AS EstHours
,PUV.ProjectStatusDate, PUV.ProjectStartDate, PUV.ProjectBaseline0StartDate, PUV.ProjectActualStartDate, PUV.ProjectStartVariance, PUV.ProjectBaseline0FinishDate
,PUV.ProjectFinishDate, PUV.ProjectFinishVariance, PUV.ProjectActualFinishDate, PUV.ProjectWork, PUV.ProjectBaseline0Work, PUV.ProjectActualWork, PUV.ProjectWorkVariance, PUV.ProjectRemainingWork
,PUV.[Project Phase], PUV.[Hold - Canceled Indicator], CWI.StageName, TB.TB_BASE_NUM, MAX (TB.CREATED_DATE) RecentBaseline
,CASE WHEN PUV.[Estimated Hours] is null then 0 END AS [Estimated%]
,Case When PUV.ProjectActualWork <> 0 THEN cast(COALESCE(PUV.ProjectActualWork,0) as DECIMAL(20,2) )/Cast(COALESCE(PUV.[Estimated Hours],0)as decimal(20,2)) Else  0 End   AS  [Estimated%]* 
--DATEDIFF(day, PUV.ProjectBaseline0FinishDate, PUV.ProjectFinishDate)
FROM  MSP_EpmProject_UserView AS PUV
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT WSI.ProjectUID, WP.PhaseName, WP.PhaseUID, WS.StageName, WS.StageUID
    FROM  MSP_EpmWorkflowStage  AS WS              
    INNER JOIN MSP_EpmWorkflowPhase AS WP ON  WS.PhaseUID = WP.PhaseUID            
    INNER JOIN MSP_EpmWorkflowStatusInformation AS WSI ON WS.StageUID = WSI.StageUID AND WSI.StageEntryDate IS NOT NULL AND (WSI.StageStatus != 0 AND WSI.StageStatus != 4)
    ) AS CWI ON PUV.ProjectUID = CWI.ProjectUID
JOIN sps_ppm_IT_Published.dbo.MSP_TASK_BASELINES AS TB ON PUV.ProjectUID = TB.PROJ_UID
WHERE TB.TB_BASE_NUM = 0
GROUP BY PUV.ProjectName, PUV.[Project ID], PUV.[Project Director], PUV.[Project Owner (Manager)], PUV.[Project Type1], PUV.[Estimated Hours]
,PUV.ProjectStatusDate, PUV.ProjectStartDate, PUV.ProjectBaseline0StartDate, PUV.ProjectActualStartDate, PUV.ProjectStartVariance, PUV.ProjectBaseline0FinishDate
,PUV.ProjectFinishDate, PUV.ProjectFinishVariance, PUV.ProjectActualFinishDate, PUV.ProjectWork, PUV.ProjectBaseline0Work, PUV.ProjectActualWork, PUV.ProjectWorkVariance, PUV.ProjectRemainingWork
,PUV.[Project Phase], PUV.[Hold - Canceled Indicator], CWI.StageName, TB.TB_BASE_NUM
ORDER BY PUV.ProjectName
```

Answer (score 0):

Your title is utterly unrelated to the question and posting a super long, aliased query from your database is not a great way to get help.

Luckily, I was curious enough to see whether "msg-8134-level-16-state-1-line-1" was a secret message from Mars that I checked it out.

Anyway, here's a small example of how to use a `CASE` statement to avoid division by zero:

```
SELECT
        CASE WHEN example.estimated_hours != 0 AND example.estimated_hours IS NOT NULL
        THEN 100 / example.estimated_hours
        ELSE 0 END AS ratio
FROM (
        SELECT estimated_hours 
        FROM (
                VALUES (0), (1), (NULL), (2), (3)) 
                AS mock_data (estimated_hours))
        AS example;
```

You can just copy/paste that into your SQL terminal and run it to see the output:

```
ratio 
-------
     0
   100
     0
    50
    33
(5 rows)
```